# Убрать рамку у input type color

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как убрать рамку у данного input?

```html
<input style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;" type="color">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чуть внимательнее смотрим в инспекторах:

```css
/* Этого хватает для FF */
input[type="color"] {
  padding: 0;
}
/* Для Chrome немного сложнее ;-) */
input[type="color" i]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 0px solid #e0e0e0;" type="color">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы это сделали)

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин а я что? Я ничего, это всё ребята. Просто торопятся с ответами зачем-то.

Answer (score 1):

```css
input {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="color">
```

Comment: Все равно же осталась серая

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, хм.. да. Но ничего лучше, чем запихать его в контейнер, теперь в голову не приходит...

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 1):

[::-moz-color-swatch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-color-swatch)

```css
input {
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: none !important;
}

::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: 0;
}

::-moz-color-swatch {
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="color">
```

Comment: Серая рамка как была так и осталась.

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Может вы под рамкой подразумеваете outline - ободку при фокусе когда курсор в поле?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Y2L5K5Zt95kVDA

Comment: Залейте полный код в какую-нибудь песочницу, такое ощущение по скрину что другие стили наследуются

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин http://jsfiddle.net/fomcpgn9/ все работает в Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102

Comment: Версия Версия 70.0.3538.102 стиль такой же как на скрине, жесткая перезагрузка и очистка кэша не помогает

Comment: А в firefox все нормально...

Comment: Все, понял о чем вы. Обновил ответ, попробуйте

Comment: Увы она осталась: http://joxi.ru/12M6Z6aHMzVb8A

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, так паддинг обнули.

Comment: @Qwertiy http://joxi.ru/a2XXKX8C1Ynoa2

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин, а я в FF смотрю...

Comment: @Qwertiy в ff и у меня все нормально, но в хроме почему то никак.